# Using like depending on string length

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I have to filter a column where data I take from the column can not look like
`'66******1'` or `'66*******1'`. So how do I use `LIKE` with different string length?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for 6 or 7 characters between the 66 and the 1? Or any string that starts with 66 and ends with 1, whatever is in between (even nothing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why should we complicate it

```
where  column not like '66_______1' or column not like  '66______1'
```

Comment: That's always true (unless the value is null); I think you meant `and` not `or`?

Answer (score 2):

You might want `regexp_like()`:

```
where not regexp_like(col, '^66[*]{6,7}1$')
```

If `*` is intended to mean any character, then:

```
where not regexp_like(col, '^66.{6,7}1$')
```

Comment: Sorry I am answering just now, it works great. Thank you

Comment: @MilosMarjanovic . . . It is surprising that you accepted an answer that is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could test for both numbers of characters with wildcards:

```
where (your_col not like '66______1' and your_col not like '66_______1')
```

If you mean for *any* number of characters between the 66 and the 1, then you can use a % wildcard instead:

```
where your_col not like '66%1'
```

which would exclude 661, 66*1, 66**1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Or, possibly, with an *ordinary* `SUBSTR`:

```
where substr(col, 1, 2) <> '66'
   or substr(col, -1)   <> '1'
```

Comment: AND seems incorect there, try OR.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple

```
WHERE col NOT LIKE '66%1'
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20063436)

Comment: @AndreaCarraro - to be fair, Alex has done that with no luck.